# Detect user key/mouse in Python Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I'm using Selenium Browser for day to day browsing, and I'd like to fire some code *when I press some keys on any page*. At first I thought I can just load javascript on every page that registers keys/mouse input, but I'd actually really prefer to have some python list available with past keys/mouse clicks, e.g. my key example in javascript:

```
var myhistory = []

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownTextField, false);

function keyDownTextField(e) {
var keyCode = e.keyCode;
  myhistory.push(keyCode)
}
```

Is there any way to do this in pure Python/Selenium?

Comment: Do I understand your question right: You sit in front of your computer and use your keyboard and selenium controls the browser on the screen and you would like to know which keys you pressed in the browser window, only using Python, no javascript code?

Comment: @User Actually, javascript is allowed. The main point is that my python session should be able to receive information.

Comment: Is there any solution for this?

Comment: @PascalVKooten Let me know if this worked for you

Comment: @Revaapriyan I added a new answer

Comment: i honestly cannot believe that it is virtually impossible to detect user input in the selenium environment *facepalm*

Answer (score 3):

What I would try:

1. Execute a javascript that registers at the document body

   ```
   <body onkeyup="my_javasctipt_keyup()" and onkeydown="my_javasctipt_keydown()">
   ```

   using `browser.execute_script`. (partially solved, see question)
2. Save the key up and keydown events in a variable in javascript. (solved, see question)
3. use `browser.execute_script` to return the variables.

What I am uncertain about:

- The return value of `browser.execute_script` may return json serializable objects or strings only
- keyup and keydown in body may not work if they are used in child elements that define their own event listeners

Hopefully this is of help. If any code results form this I would be interested in knowing.

This code is what I feel should work:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.execute_script("""var myhistory = []

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownTextField, false);

function keyDownTextField(e) {
var keyCode = e.keyCode;
  myhistory.push(keyCode)
}""")
def get_history():
    return browser.execute_script("myhistory")

# now wait for a while and type on the browser
import time; time.sleep(5000)

print("keys:", get_history())
```

The point is that the code of selenium can never run at the same time as the browser handles keyboard input. As such, events need to be handled in javascript, the result saved, e.g. in an array and then, when selenium is asked, the array is returned to Python.

Comment: nope. It's not working. both the statements return None in code but works fine in chrome console.

    `driver = webdriver.Chrome()`
    `driver.get("chrome://dino/")`
    `script = "window.onkeydown = function(e){return e.which;}"`
    `while True:`
        `print(driver.execute_script(script),end=" .. ")`

This prints `None .. None .. None .. None ..`...

Comment: I expect your code to print None. I adapted the code above and added the last 4 lines. What do you think? The point is that the code of selenium can never run at the same time as the browser handles keyboard input. As such, events need to be handled in javascript, the result saved, e.g. in an array and then when selenium is asked, the array is returned to python.

Comment: `def get_history(driver):`
    `return driver.execute_script("myhistory")`
`driver = webdriver.Chrome()`
`driver.get("chrome://dino/")`
`driver.execute_script("""var myhistory = []`
`document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownTextField, false);`
`function keyDownTextField(e) {`
`var keyCode = e.keyCode;`
`  myhistory.push(keyCode)`
`}"""`)`
`time.sleep(5)`
`while True:`
    `driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.ARROW_UP)`
    `print(get_history(driver))`

But This results in error: 
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: "myhistory" is not defined

Comment: chrome version = Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 1):

`boppreh/keyboard` would let you do that.
You install it. `pip install keyboard`
You import it. `import keyboard`
You use it. `keyboard.add_hotkey('left', print, args=['You pressed the left arrow key'])`
Then you disable it. `keyboard.remove_all_hotkeys()`

Answer (score 0):

Well, in that case you had to choose the right tool for the job, i advice [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) a web-automation family instrument a pure-made JS, which can easily interact with the browser ( from js to js ) and catch events directly from the other side without any mediation.

Yet with selenium you can still achieve this transitively without messing too much with the pages's code or overcharging it with unnecessary tasks, also reloading the page content resets all its variables, which means it's lossy approach. The best closest way is to set an eventhandler internally and directly catch it from outside using `Runtime.evaluate` instead because it doesn't affect the page content and specifically it sticks to the function until it yields something using promise calls, it's better away than probing around some global variable over and over which is seen a bad practise see [here](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Runtime#method-evaluate).

```
myhistory = []
evt_handler = """
new Promise((rs,rj) => window.onkeydown= e => rs(e.keyCode) )
"""
def waitforclick():
    try:
        myhistory.append(browser.execute_cdp_cmd('Runtime.evaluate', {'expression': evt_handler, 'awaitPromise': True,'returnByValue': True})['result']['value'])
    except:
        waitforclick()
```

To avoid locking out the cpu you need to fork a thread in parallel.

```
from threading import Timer 
t = Timer(0.0, waitforclick)
```

then `t.start()` instead of `waitforclick()`.

Also you can use `timeout` if you want to reject the promise with a zero value after some time.